# What qualifies as first generation

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

Sometimes, I feel that the term "first generation" is used sort of vaguely sometimes. So it confuses me (because my situation) is a little bit complicated.

My dad, was an immigrant from a foreign country and lived here long enough to get a passport. That way, he has an American citizenship. My mom, wasn't born in the US and doesn't have a US citizenship.

I wasn't born in the US, so am I a first generation American? Or do I just have a citizenship (because of my dad's American citizenship)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "first generation" is often used to describe both people born abroad and their descendants, which is terribly confusing. The [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/first-generation?q=%22first%20generation%22) covers both meanings.

Assuming you are living in the US and were born abroad, you are a first-generation immigrant. I wouldn’t include citizenship in the mix. You can use “first-generation American” regardless.

> Designating the first of a generation to become a citizen in a new country.
>
> Designating the first of a generation to be born in a country of parents who had immigrated

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! But one last question... does that make me second-generation (Because my father got a citizenship)?

Comment: You are welcome Eames. You is a lot of ambiguity with second-generation too. I would use second-generation if you were born in the country.